# Logging/Progress indicator when deploying Azure ARM template via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template that I use to deploy something into Azure via the PowerShell cmdlet `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`.

The deployment itself works fine but takes a long time (15 to 21 minutes).

While the cmdlet is deploying the template, it just silently sits there; i.e. it doesn't print out any progress information.

Is there a way to make `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` print out what it's doing?

I already tried the `-DeploymentDebugLogLevel` parameter but just got warnings and couldn't figure out how to use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve some output would be to add the `-Verbose` switch to the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`, it would query the deployment every once in a while (usually 5 seconds intervals) and spit out something to the screen.

Alternatively you could create a deployment by using rest api and query the deployment progress yourself, that would require some development thou.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.